# Trying to get 4 pictures into a grid but can't see what I'm doing wrong

Tags: html, css

So here's what I want to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqD5B.jpg

However I can't seem to get the pictures to line up. I have done in previous pages but not on this one and applying the same technique doesn't work. Here is my HTML:

```
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <img src="images/food.gif" alt="Our Food" id="food-image">

            <div id="food">

                <div id="food-description">

                    <p>What better way to complement your wine other than food?
                    That’s right nothing. Unless it’s a large pile of money or a yacht.
                    Unfortunately we don’t have either of these so you’ll have to make
                    do with our varied selection of food.</p>

                    <div class="food-grid">

                        <img src="images/pringles.jpg" alt="Picture of our Pringles" class="food-pictures">
                        <img src="images/chocolate.jpg" alt="Picture of our Chocolate" class="food-pictures">
                        <img src="images/hampers.jpg" alt="Picture of our Hampers" class="food-pictures">
                        <img src="images/happy-shopper.jpg" alt="Picture of our Happy Shopper Products" class="food-pictures">

                    </div><!--end of food-grid"-->

                    <p>Why not have some Cadbury’s with your Merlot? Or some
                    Pringles and salsa dip with your Pinot Grigio? On the
                    other hand, maybe you’re looking for a gift for a chocoholic?
                    They would love a Cadbury’s Milk Tray or Nestle Dairy Box.
                    Pair that with our Chocoholic Pinotage and you’re golden.</p>

                </div><!--end of food-description-->



            </div><!--end of food-->

        </div><!--end of container-->

    </div><!--end of content-->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#food-image {
display: block;
margin: 25px auto 50px;
}

#food-description {
font-size: 35px;
color: #78035c;
line-height: 38px;
text-align: center;
}

.food-grid {
text-align: center;
}

.food-pictures {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Any chance anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Pictures display vertically http://i.imgur.com/ZpcdWK5.jpg

Comment: That means that the images are too wide to fit on the same line. Try restricting the width of the images to 50% as @IbrahimAlkan suggested.

Comment: But the image should be able to fit on the same line, it is under 960px which is how big the width of the website is. I have restricted the width to 50% like @IbrahimAlkan said and it worked but I don't really understand why

Comment: If the width of the containing element is 960px, that means that your images can only be, at max, 480px wide. This doesn't take into account margins/paddings/etc. So if your images are any larger than 480px wide, that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: The images were 471px and with a 2px margin on the left and right. They would of been 479px which would of been enough

Comment: There must be some other margin/padding that is being added by the browser that is making the images too wide. Regardless, it's better to define a `max-width` via CSS than to worry about saving all of your images with the exact dimensions necessary for them to display on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
.food-pictures {
display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y9fyucyz/

If you want to add gap in pictures.
like

```
.food-pictures {
    display: inline-block;
        width:45%;
        margin:1%;
        float:left;
}
```

You can use css margin. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah this worked but I don't understand why using width: 50% worked. I made it so the images would fit onto the page as their pixel widths together don't go over the pixel width of the website

Comment: Actualy its not width. Its about float:left. If you dont float them each element acting like in a line.

Comment: `float:left;` is unnecessary here. `display:inline-block;` takes care of displaying the images on the same line.

Comment: Even when I add float:left without the width, it still does not go with 2 images on one line

Comment: What is your images widths and heights ?

Comment: 471 width and 305 height

Comment: its not about float:left in this case is unnecessary. display:inline-block does the job

Comment: So it seems your images are bigger than your max width. Your screen can be 960px but maybe your container is smaller than 960px. You need minimum 942px for 2 picture.